# divive the list element with number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following list element.

> cb = [(31000, 61000), (59000, 61000), (59000, 227000), (31000,
>   227000), (31000, 61000)]

and diving element by 1000 in following way.Do we have any more better way to do following operation in python

```
left_x = float(cb.coords[0][0]/1000)
left_y = float(cb.coords[0][1]/1000)
right_x = float(cb.coords[2][0]/1000)
up_y = float(cb.coords[2][1]/1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could divide the whole list by 1000 at the start. This could help you avoid errors in which you forget to divide by 1000 or something, I guess.

```
cb = [tuple(x/1000 for x in tup) for tup in cb]
left_x, left_y = cb[0] # automatically unpack tuples
right_x, up_y = cb[2]
```

Comment: yeah! i was writing in comments for automatic unpacking. :)